# CustomPaint paints on widgets below it. How to avoid it?

Tags: flutter

I have a CustomPaoint size 300, 300. And below this I have other widgets. I also have a Listener that tracks the down and move positions and adds the Offset to a List. This List is used for state change and sent to CustomPainter to paint it.

It all works fine. If I tap down outside the bounds of the CustomPaint widget then it does not paint. However if I tap inside the CustomPaint and move outside of it then the Offsets are records and used for painting and this results in painting in other widgets below the CustomPaint.

How can I avoid it? Below is my code.

```
class DrawingCanvas extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new DrawingCanvasState();

}

class DrawingCanvasState extends State<DrawingCanvas> {

  GlobalKey _paintKey = new GlobalKey();
  List<Offset> _finalOffsets = <Offset>[];

  DrawingCanvasState() {
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Listener(
      onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent pdEvent) {
        RenderBox referenceBox = _paintKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        Offset localOffset = referenceBox.globalToLocal(pdEvent.position);
        setState((){
          this._finalOffsets.clear();
          this._finalOffsets.add(localOffset);
        });
      },
      onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent pmEvent) {
        RenderBox referenceBox = _paintKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        Offset localOffset = referenceBox.globalToLocal(pmEvent.position);
        setState((){
          this._finalOffsets.add(localOffset);
        });
      },
      onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent puEvent){
      },
      onPointerCancel: (PointerCancelEvent pcEvent){
      },
      child: new CustomPaint(
        key: _paintKey,
        size: new Size(300.0, 300.0),
        isComplex: true,
        willChange: true,
        painter: new CanvasPainter(this._finalOffsets),
        child: new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints.tightForFinite(width: 300.00, height: 300.00),
        ),
      ),
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
    );
  }
}

class CanvasPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> _offsets;

  CanvasPainter(List<Offset> pOffsets){
    this._offsets = pOffsets;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.color = Colors.black;
    p.strokeWidth = 5.0;
    p.isAntiAlias = true;
    p.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    p.strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;
    p.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.polygon, this._offsets, p);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578209/how-to-touch-paint-a-canvas?rq=1
    //print("should repaint check called");
    return true;
  }
}
```

NOTE - The DrawingCanvas is used in another Column Widget. And there are two Widgets below it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, I just changed my code to follow the code as per the answer in the below question.

[How to touch paint a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578209/how-to-touch-paint-a-canvas)